# Can you use shorthand property assignment using 'this'?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I can do this:

```
class Temp {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = 'foo'
        this.bar = 'bar'
    }

    getObj() {

        let boo = 'boo'
        return {
            boo
        }
    }
}
console.log(new Temp().getObj())
//prints { boo: 'boo' }
```

So how can I do this:

```
class Temp {
    constructor() {
        this.foo = 'foo'
        this.bar = 'bar'
    }

    getObj() {

        return {
            this.foo
        }
    }
}
console.log(new Temp().getObj())
```

Is there special syntax or is it not supported?

Comment: Why do you need another special syntax? to get rid of those nasty four (!!) characters in `{ foo: this.foo, }` ?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms consistency and lower risk of error? Imagine that this is just an example and I may have a huge list of key/value pairs.

Comment: ... at the cost of weird syntax mixes.

Comment: wait... do you just want to clone the class or extract only certain values?

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you actually look for is:

```
return { ...this };
```

or if you want to omit some properties:

```
 const { bar, ...take } = this;
 return take;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not yet supported. You will have to go by `{foo: this.foo}`.

However, there is a [stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/rbuckton/proposal-shorthand-improvements) for shorthand property definition improvements that would allow you to write `{this.foo}` as an object literal.

Comment: hmmm ... there was always confusion between block statements and object literals, not sure if that proposal makes it even harder to distinguish ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Normally it's pretty obvious that you're in an expression context - when you are reading the whole code not getting presented an excerpt that could be both. I'd really love this proposal to get accepted, I was wanting this for years…

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use destructuring, you'll need to extract the property to a const, and then use shorthand property names:

```js
class Temp {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'foo'
    this.bar = 'bar'
  }

  getObj() {
    const { foo } = this;

    return {
      foo
    }
  }
}
console.log(new Temp().getObj())
```

Comment: I don't believe that's destructuring in the way I was expecting. Notice in my example that the key is the same name of the var without having to type it in.

Comment: I've added an answer with destructuring.

Comment: Yes, my question was confusing. I was getting shorthand properties mixed with destructuring (i.e. I'm fairly new to js)

Answer (score 0):

If 'foo' is a public property you can do something like this:

```
class Foo {
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
  }
}

const { foo } = (new Foo());
console.log(foo); // 'foo'
```

https://repl.it/repls/FastForcefulMice

Comment: Hmm, now I feel like I need to change the title to my question. So was asking if you can use shorthand property names with 'this'.

Comment: @u84six You can't.